# How to maximize file writing speed with less memory consumption?

Tags: android, randomaccessfile

Ok, my question is how can I maximize file writing speed with less memory consumption?

I am making an android app for transferring file from one device to the other device via Wifi-direct.

I am using RandomAccessFile to write to the file.
raf.write(byte[], offset, length);

There are these two situations --
1. If I use RandomAccessFile with "rws" mode, the file write is slow but the device memory remains available for other uses.
2. If I use RandomAccessFile with "rw" mode, the file write speed is ok but it fills the device memory (the device which is receiving the file) probably because it writes to the file asynchronously and so it creates a buffer for holding the content to be written asynchronously.

So exactly how can I manage the amount of memory used for writing asynchronously (with "rw" mode)?
Or how can I improve file writing speed with less memory consumption if there is any other way?

Comment: With RandomAccessFile? Why not just use FileOutputStream?

Comment: FileOutputStream is good but it too consumes more memory, I want to manage the memory used by RandomAccessFile or FileOutputStream.

Comment: Where does FileOutputStream consume memory? It does not matter how big the file is, the used memory will be the same and little. Please show figures.

Comment: Actually I'm using a SQLite database to store all the file transfers which are done by my app. I insert a row in the table when the file transfer begins and at the end of transfer I update the status column as completed of that row which I inserted. So the problem is the update takes a very long time (around 15s) to complete when the file size is large (say 400mb). It takes around 3s to update if the file size is 50mb and takes ms if file size is very less (less than 10mb). So I thought it is because of less memory available.

Comment: If I use RandomAccessFile with "rws" mode, it takes ms to update even if the file size is large.